# Java 10 and JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-module

I have this third party DLL file which seems to have been compiled using the global namespace.  Before this was working since we were using Java8 but this broke when we migrated to Java10.

Our Java class that contains our native keywords is dllCommunication.java. In Java 8 we were doing this:

```
Class.forName("dllCommunication");
```

In Java 10 we were forced to do this because no .class files allowed in default package:

```
Class.forName("com.jni.dllCommunication");
```

And get that Java unsatisfiedLink error.

The main application is a self contained Java desktop application that contains the JRE using the module-info.java file.  So my question is if there is a way to include the dllCommunication.java in the default package without Java10 complaining about it?

Any reasonable solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: I'll address this tomorrow. Sounds interesting. Bookmarked.